# Qt need help to disable scroll on combobox

Tags: qt

Hello I need help to turn off scrool on combobox , I have written some code but I get error, can someone help me

```
list << ui->comboBox << ui->comboBox_2 << ui->comboBox_3;
for(i =0 ; i<list.count();i++)
{
    list[i]->installEventFilter(this);
    list[i]->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
}


bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * o,QEvent * e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::Wheel && o == list.at(i) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

When i run program i get this Error

> ASSERT failure in QList::at: "index out of range"

Comment: Please, provide an SSCCE.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but in `o == list.at(i)` you don't set `i`, which might be equal to `list.count()` from the earlier code. As noted above, please provide a [Small, Self-Contained Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start in debug mode see where is the error.
solution: remove o == list.at(i)

Comment: II got the same error                                                                                              ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file ..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 456
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Comment: Of course you get. You can use `.at()` method instead of `operator[]` and you get en exception instead of assert. You just call `operator[]` with index that is not exist. In debug mode you can find the place where you do it.

Comment: Program Start but when i try to change combobox index i get that Error

Comment: add qDebug() <<  i << list.count(); before if, to see values

Comment: I do that i get values "3",Is there any other way to turn off Scroll on combobox ?

Comment: in eventFilter function where variable i is declared? try too remove o == list.at(i)

Comment: Thank you so much and no more errors and Scrool is off.Hvala puno :D